# Magento 2.3 adding coupon code on a custom payment page

Tags: php, magento, magento2, payment, coupon

I have a custom payment page (the user is not seeing the cart page they go directly to the custom payment page) and I want to add the coupon field to the page, but can't figure out how to go about it.

My payment.php file has the function execute where the items are added to the cart:

```
  public function execute()
  {
   .
   .
   .
    $this->cart->truncate();
    $quote = $this->cart->getQuote();
    $item = $this->addPricingPlanToCart($pricingPlan, $product->getId());

    $quote = $this->cart->getQuote();
    $this->quoteRepository->save($quote);
    $logger->info("Final ".print_r($this->cart->getQuote()->getGrandTotal(),true));
  .
  .
  .
  }
```

Thank you for any help pro!
Please let me know if more details are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way. Ref [[github: crankycyclops]](https://github.com/crankycyclops/DiscountCodeUrl/blob/master/Helper/Cart.php)

```
public function __construct(
\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
...
$this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
}
...

$quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();
$quote->setCouponCode($coupon);
$this->quoteRepository->save($quote->collectTotals());
```